# scorm player by using html and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, moodle, scorm1.2, scorm-cloud-api

I am new to SCORM & I am looking to create a simple SCORM player . I have searched everywhere on internet but still no luck! Also I don't want to use anything like scorm.com engine and any other paid service. Moodle & Scormpool also didn't help much. I want a code that plays scorm packages on my browser in html, JavaScript. Please guide me from where I should start and how can I built it.

Comment: In what way were moodle & scormpool insufficient for what you need? What have you tried and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: There's nothing simple about Scorm :) I wouldn't advise developing a scorm player from scratch. The one in Moodle has been developed over many years. What is your requirement? Scorm sends a lot of data to Moodle.

Comment: My team is building a eLearning website and I have to make scorm player in that web site. But I am not able to get any resource for scorm player from internet. So, please help me. @AndrewDownes

Comment: from where I can get resources to know how to built scorm player @RussellEngland